# Cannot use OUTPUT clause with INTO clause when using Triggers to update records in SQL, when adding a record in FileMaker

Tags: sql, sql-server, filemaker

I know a similar question to this has been asked a fair few times on here, but none seem to give me the answer I need - specifically because I am talking about the relationship between SQL and FileMaker.

See, I'm not actually using an OUTPUT clause at all in my Trigger! But FileMaker seems to either think I am, or insert something itself as an OUTPUT clause that I can't see.

Here is an example trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[TRG_person__name] 
   ON  [dbo].[person] 
   AFTER INSERT,UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

IF  UPDATE ( person_name_first ) 
    BEGIN

        UPDATE person
        SET person_name_first = dbo.mslTitleCase ( i.person_name_first )
        FROM person AS x
        JOIN inserted AS i ON x._pk_person = i._pk_person
        WHERE x._pk_person = i._pk_person

    END
--END IF


END
```

The mslTitleCase function has been declared and works, if I was to create a record using a SQL Query. 
But I can an error when creating a new record in FileMaker.

Does anyone have any tips to find a way to stop this error in FileMaker?

Any guidance greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Lewis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been reported as a bug: http://help.filemaker.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/7870/~/external-sql-data-sources-(ess)%3A-unable-to-write-to-a-table-with-triggers-on

It does not look like it was resolved.

Comment: Thanks Nicolai - maybe my email was too vague! Looks like I'll have to find another way to do insert, but updates work just fine triggers.

Answer (score 1):

You may have other problems, but the correct syntax for the `update` is:

```
    UPDATE p
        SET person_name_first = dbo.mslTitleCase ( i.person_name_first )
    FROM person p JOIN
         inserted i
         ON p._pk_person = i._pk_person
    WHERE p._pk_person = i._pk_person;
```

The important change is that the `update` references the *table alias* not the *table name*.  I think `p` is a much better alias than `x` for a table named `person`.

Comment: Thank you for your help - I'll update my triggers to use this best practice.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your application is using the OUTPUT clause to directly return the modified data.  If the table has any trigger, this is not allowed.  They would have to output the modified data into a table, and then select the data from the table.

The issue is covered in this article:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlprogrammability/2008/07/11/update-with-output-clause-triggers-and-sqlmoreresults/

If this is the case, you will not be able to add a trigger to the table.  The corrections to the data will need to happen from an external source.